# php upload error=0 and file doesn't exixt

Tags: php, file-upload, temporary-files, php-5.6

After updating to php 5.6.17 (Centos 6.5) files are not uploading.

$_FILES variable dump below

```
Array(
[files] => Array
    (
        [name] => file.pdf
        [type] => application/pdf
        [tmp_name] => /etc/folder/temp/phprm2HZS
        [error] => 0
        [size] => 1500433
    )
```

)

if I try `file_exists($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'])` returns false

if I list the contents of that temp folder it's empty, and surely `move_uploaded_file` returns false, and no exception is caught.

Edit:

Problem was that /tmp is not in apache's open_basedir

Fixed now

Comment: check the permission of the folder

Comment: Also rememeber, the file only exists in the tmp folder until the script processing the file upload completes. Then PHP automatically deletes the temp file. So if you have not done a `move_upoaded_file()` or similiar before the script finishes, its gone forever

Answer (score 1):

You try something like

```
$path = '/uploads'; // path of your image upload folder 

if( chmod($path, 0777) ) {
     move_uploaded_file ( string $filename , string $destination ){
        //rest code
     }
}
```